# Count of dropdowns selected a particular value inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a solution for count of dropdowns inside a div where dropdowns selected a particular value.
In details
Div contains multiple drop downs I am looking for number of dropdowns selected a value let's say "Show".

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Add some HTML to show us what your working with, please.

Comment: So are you trying to have multiple values selectable in a dropdown?

Comment: VIDesignz:It's dynamically generated html all i can say is Div contains many dropdowns

Comment: BelgianMyWaffle:No only one value is selectable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/9d8Sr/)

```
$("select", "div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).val() == "Show"
}).length;
```

Comment: can you please update with div name "divInStateContent" this div contains many dynamically generated select boxes

Comment: @user2217726 Just change the selector to `div#divInStateContent`, what's the problem?

Comment: Barmar:I updated like $("select", "divInStateContent").filter(function () {
                    return $(this).val() == "Show"
                }).length; but it gave me zero

Comment: Kei:Can you tell me how can i modifie to text value instead of val()

Comment: `return $("option:selected",this).text() == "Show";`

Comment: kei: var inStateCount = $("select", "#divInStateContent").filter(function () {
                    $("option:selected", this).text() == "Eligible";
                }).length;
                alert(inStateCount);getting zero

Comment: working forgot to add return..thank you kei